# Angular-Calling function result in HTML

Tags: html, angular

I have a function in my ts file:

```
makeid(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
 }
```

And what I want is to return result of this function in my html. I can call a funtion in html like:

```
<input [readonly]="true" formControlName="caseId" matInput placeholder="Radni nalog br:" value="{{ makeid(15) }}">
```

But every time I click anywhere, it changes the value, and I'm getting an error:

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the component reloads it will change because the function will run again.
To keep the value of the first call use a variable to store the value on `ngOnInit()`

Examle:

```js
x: string;


ngOnInit(){

    this.x = makeid(15)

}


makeid(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
 }
```

And in the HTML:

```
<input [readonly]="true" formControlName="caseId" matInput placeholder="Radni nalog br:" [value]="x">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `[( ngModel )]` or put a variable in your `component.ts` file and change that variable with your function and html will change automatically:

something like this

```
 <input id="Last Name" name="Last Name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" />
```

this stackblitz will help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-value-changes-v2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html